# Sending (nested) json object with file using Postman

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest, postman

With Postman, I can attach files in requests with form-data, I can also send nested JSON object in raw format, but how can I do both: sending nested-structure data with file, e.g:

```
"data": {
    "normal_fields": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
    },
    "image_file": <file>
}
```

Comment: just convert your file to byte array and add the result to your JSON

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting values like below and choose file to upload.

[image]

Comment: I have a very big json array, so is there a way to directly attach the file in raw json format

Comment: This is not practical at all, if we have long json content. Is there any other way to do simultaniously send json and file together?

Comment: Does this still work? I've tried and it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking a few years later, you need to send it as
`normal_fields.field1`
something like [image]

Comment: This needs more upvotes, was struggling to make it work and this made it!

Answer (score 1):

It didn't worked for me like that. For me only worked this way:

```
property[nested_field1]
property[nested_field2]
```

or arrays with objects:

```
array[0][nested_field1]
array[0][nested_field2]
array[1][nested_field1]
array[1][nested_field2]
```

Comment: In fact my question is not about sending nested fields but "sending file with nested fields". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone needs to send an array of files, this syntax worked for me:

```
<field_name>[0]
<field_name>[1]
...
<field_name>[n]
```

But if you are sending files as an array of nested objects:
I.e.

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "file": <file>
        },
        {
            "file": <file>
        },
    ]
}
```

Then try this:

```
files[0]file
files[1]file
```