# Spring MVC - Parsing a request containing a Map within an object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller using SpringMVC that takes in an object for the body. The object is currently made up of strings, I want to add a map as part of the request object is that possible?

Example

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public ModelAndView create(@Valid Car car)
```

Car

```
public class Car{
    @NotNull
    private String name ;

    @NotNull
    private String model;

    private Map<String, String> parts; //Want to add this

    //getters and setters
}
```

If possible, what is the format used to send the data when consuming an application form (APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your payload should be like below:

```
{
"name":"sample",
"model":"sample",
"parts":{
        "key":"value"
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that it will only be consuming   APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269536/4597596

Comment: Ended up using a String (as json) and using gson to parse into a map. Thanks for your input.