# Sending nested json object with file using Postman

Tags: arrays, object, request, postman, form-data

I figured out how to send a file next to other params using form-data. Now I need to send a file inside a nested object, specificially the file key is inside a key and then in an array. Like this:

```
"data": {
    "normal_field": [
        {
             "field1": "value1",
             "field2": "value2",
             "image_file": <file>
        }, (etc)
    ]
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269536/126927739) answer, my current setup looks like this
[image]

I sadly get a Bad Request back, and I am also not able to figure out a way to view the raw request Postman generates, so I have to assume the keys I input are wrong. If you want a more specific scenario, I am trying to use [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup) method.

Comment: You can view the raw request in the console

Comment: @poolitzer
I am facing the same problem. have you got any solution for this?

Comment: the specific method didn't require to add the file inside the nested dict, you add it as a high level key value pair and then pass the key of the file as value in image_file. So I didn't solve it, sorry

Comment: It's basically not supported for nested json. i just saw it on forum