# how to send a json with neseted fields and files in postman

Tags: json, postman

I need to send a json object like this :

```
 {
  
    "title": "tour1",
    "description": "lets go updated",
    "date_time": "2021-06-30T06:14:00Z",
    "time_zone": "Africa/Abidjan",
    "host": 1,
    "is_private": true,
    "is_virtual": false,
    "url": "www.google.com",
    "photos": [
        {
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/meeting-photos/1.jpg"
            
          
        },
        {
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/meeting-photos/5.jpg"
            
         
        },
        {
            "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/meeting-photos/3_Os8n2RX.jpg"
            
            
        }
    ],

   "location":{
     "lat": "0.0000000000000003",
     "lng": "0.0000000000000002"
    }
}
```

based on this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351869/sending-nested-json-object-with-file-using-postman/31269536#31269536)  i put the nested location field in bulk edit and the result was like this :[image: postman form data]
but when i posted the json i got this error :

```
KeyError: 'location'
```

what should i do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems lie here:
[image]

and you should not send " as key.

You are treating form data like JSON, instead, you need to use it as key:value mapping. See image below for how your request should look like:
[image]